# Python script fails when moved to server - (Matplotlib versioning)

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have this python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import time
#from scipy.interpolate import spline

def myround(x, base=24*3600):
    return int(base * round(float(x)/base))

def processFile(filename):
    file = open(filename)
    lastrawline="Hello"
    rawline = file.readline()
    #the array we have is going to be horizonal when we need vertical. So we have to deal with that. 
    dayold=[]
    weekold=[]
    threedayold=[]
    seconds=[]
    now=[]
    count=0
    for rawline in file:
        splitline=rawline.split()
        dayold.insert(0,splitline[4])
        threedayold.insert(0,splitline[5])
        weekold.insert(0,splitline[3])
        seconds.insert(0,splitline[2])
        now.insert(0,splitline[0])
            count=count+1   
    return (seconds,now,dayold,threedayold,weekold)

def graph(seconds,now, dayold, threedayold,weekold):
    dis=4*24*60*60
    x = np.array(seconds[-dis:])

    #x = np.arange(len(seconds))
    ynow = np.array(now)
    yday = np.array(dayold)
    y3day = np.array(threedayold)
    yweek = np.array(weekold)
    # y2 should go on top, so shift them up
    plt.plot(x,ynow, 'white')
    plt.plot(x,yday)
    plt.plot(x,y3day,'purple')
    plt.plot(x,yweek)
    plt.fill_between(x,ynow,yday,color='lightblue')
    plt.fill_between(x,yday,y3day,color='green')
    plt.fill_between(x,y3day,yweek,color='purple')
    plt.fill_between(x,yweek,[0] *len(seconds),color='red')
    currenttime=int(seconds[0])
    print currenttime
    lastweek=myround(currenttime-7*24*3600)
    print lastweek
    plt.xlim(lastweek, currenttime)
    ticks=np.arange(lastweek,currenttime,24*3600)
    labels=[time.strftime("%a", time.gmtime(x)) for x in ticks]
    plt.xticks(ticks,labels)
    plt.grid()
#   plt.show()
    plt.savefig('stress.png')

#processFile("/home/pgrads/joseph/Dropbox/emailAnalysis/resultsOldest.txt")
a=processFile("results.txt")
graph(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4])
```

That produces this graph, which is great.

[image]

At least on my local machine.

When I upload it to a server it throws the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./plotNextActionData.py", line 63, in <module>
    graph(a[0],a[1],a[2],a[3],a[4])
  File "./plotNextActionData.py", line 45, in graph
    plt.fill_between(x,ynow,yday,color='lightblue')
  File "/home/joereddington/env/matplotlib-1.4.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 2820, in fill_between
    interpolate=interpolate, **kwargs)
  File "/home/joereddington/env/matplotlib-1.4.0-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/matplotlib/axes/_axes.py", line 4316, in fill_between
    x = ma.masked_invalid(self.convert_xunits(x))
  File "/home/joereddington/env/numpy-1.8.2-py2.6-linux-x86_64.egg/numpy/ma/core.py", line 2239, in masked_invalid
    condition = ~(np.isfinite(a))
TypeError: Not implemented for this type
```

Commenting out the fill_between calls generates a graph nicely 
[image]

It's just not the one I want. Any idea what's happened? MatplotLib is clearly working, just these calls are difficult...

EDIT - Versions.

Home machine:

```
josephs-mbp-3$more scrap.py 
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot 
#from scipy.interpolate import spline

print np.__version__
print matplotlib.__version__
josephs-mbp-3$python scrap.py 
1.6.2
1.1.1
josephs-mbp-3$
```

Server:

```
 blout$more scrap.py 
import numpy as np
import time
import matplotlib.pyplot 
#from scipy.interpolate import spline

print np.__version__
print matplotlib.__version__
blout$python scrap.py 
1.8.2
1.4.0
```

Comment: Can you do a `pip freeze` and check if the versions of `numpy` and `matplotlib` are same on both you local and server environment?

Comment: Checking versions produced an odd result... have added content...

Comment: That seems to be the output on the server only, what is the output of the script on your local machine, does it print versions for both numpy and matplotlib?

Comment: you want `matplotlib.__version__` not `plt.__version__`

Comment: And I suspect that is something to do with the cleaning of your input

Comment: I've added version information - (my first was wrong as tcaswell pointed out) server is a higher version... Am I missing something?